# Mysql table data problem?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql and was wondering how can I add the users birthdate in the following HTML format to the MYSQL table data listed below?

How would the structure look like for example `email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,`?

Here is the HTML code below.

```
    <li><label>Date of Birth: </label>
    <label for="month">Month: </label>
        <select name="month" id="month">
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="February">February</option>
            <option value="March">March</option>
            <option value="April">April</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
            <option value="June">June</option>
            <option value="July">July</option>
            <option value="August">August</option>
            <option value="September">September</option>
            <option value="October">October</option>
            <option value="November">November</option>
            <option value="December">December</option>  
        </select>
    <label for="day">Day: </label>
        <select id="day" name="day">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Day</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>                   
    <label for="year">Year: </label><input type="text" name="year" id="year" /></li>
```

Here is the MySQL table data.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
pass CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
user_level TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
active CHAR(32),
registration_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
UNIQUE KEY (email),
INDEX login (email, pass)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a date, you can use the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) datatype :

> The `DATE` type is used when you need
>   only a date value, without a time
>   part. 
> MySQL retrieves and displays
>   `DATE` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD'`
>   format. 
> The supported range is
>   `'1000-01-01'` to `'9999-12-31'`.

Then, you'll insert/update or get dates using a `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format.

This means your create table would look like this :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
active CHAR(32),
registration_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
birthdate DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
...
);
```

And you'd use SQL queries such as *(examples)* :

```
select * 
from users 
where birthdate >= '1980-01-01' and birthdate <= '1999-12-31'
```

And/or :

```
insert into users (..., birthdate, ...) 
values (..., '1965-03-24', ...)
```

And/or :

```
update users
set birthdate = '1988-05-12'
where uid_id = 125
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [DATETIME/DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) field to store this.

Comment: how would it look like in my Mysql table?

Comment: Somethinf like **bithday DATETIME DEFAULT NULL**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) datatype for the birthday.

If you want to recreate the table you can add:

```
birth_day DATE NOT NULL,
```

If its not possible to have a b'day for every user you can drop the `NOT NULL` clause.

If you want to alter the existing table you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD COLUMN birth_day DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DATE` type in a table

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    pass CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    user_level TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    active CHAR(32),
    registration_date DATETIME NOT NULL,

    birhtday DATE NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    UNIQUE KEY (email),
    INDEX login (email, pass)
    );
```

You better modify your form, so that `value` of month options would be numbers, not full month names. Like this:

```
         <select name="month" id="month">
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>  
        </select>
```

If you are using PHP, the code that would make a proper value for a `DATE` type:

```
<?php
    //$birthday will be something like '7-12-1985'
    $birthday = $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];
?>
```